# Split time to intervals

Tags: python, datetime

I have a dataset which time is in this format `HH:MM:SS`.

I want to create intervals groups of 15min periods. For example

`00:00-00:14, 00:15-00:29, 00:30-00:44, .......`

And then add the entries in each group. Is there any way to do this with the Datetime module of Python or I have to do it manual?

Comment: You already have a dataset of times, or do you want to create such a dataset? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: I wrote on the first line that I have this dataset and I want to divide it in intervals.

Comment: Just round the times from the dataset down to the previous 15 minute slot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

May be this is what you are looking for

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> curr = datetime.now()
>>> seq1 = []
>>> for x in range(10):
...     curr = curr + timedelta(minutes = 15)
...     seq1.append(curr.strftime("%H:%M"))
...
>>> seq1
['06:20', '06:35', '06:50', '07:05', '07:20', '07:35', '07:50', '08:05', '08:20', '08:35']
>>>
```